# Error doble elemento predeterminado del menú

Tags: joomla3

He tenido un problema en el Main Menu de mi Joomla 3.9.18.

Se han marcado 2 elementos del menú como predeterminados y no me deja eliminar uno de ellos. 
Cuando intento eliminar uno de ellos, me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

> "Error Se ha producido un fallo al guardar con el siguiente error: Como
>   mínimo debe haber un elemento del menú configurado como el
>   predeterminado."

Tengo que dejar uno sólo. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionarlo?

[image: Error doble elemento predeterminado del menú]

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ve a p**hpMyAdmin**, dentro busca la tabla **xxxx_menu**, *xxxx es el prefijo de tu base de datos*.

- Da clic **"Examinar"**, ahí podrás ver el elemento "Currículum Vitae" de tu captura de pantalla.
- Da clic en **"Editar"**, cambia de **"1"** a **"0"** el valor en **"home"** y da clic en **Continuar** para actualizar. Esto desactivará el elemento como predeterminado para Inicio.

Listo!